# latex enumerate custom numerical order

Tags: latex, numbers, tex, enumerate

are there any simple: almost a single liner latex commands to make [enumerate](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) count in a weird order for instance that of a homework assignment?

Ex. 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 16

Comment: You could always use `\setcounter`. Anyway, this question belongs on http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it easily with:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item[1] text text...
  \item[5] text text...
  \item[6] text text...
  \item[9] text text...
\end{enumerate}
```